# Dropdown menu to push contents below when opened

Tags: css

Im having difficulties with getting the elements below my submenu to push downwards when the submenu opens. I have set the ".parent" LI to position:relative and ".sub-menu.open", the sub menu container, to position:absolute. So currently all the parents such as "Product, Company, Connect" stay in place when the menu opens. I was able to figure out how to position the submenu.open when it is toggled. Now Im just stuck in figuring out how to get the contents below to move downwards. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```css
ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: $footer-text;
  width: 50%;
  color: $darkblue-headingtext;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[image: current display]

Comment: You did give it a property `display: block;` instead of `display: flex;` so the flex-direction will not work. It is not the answer to your question but you have to decide between block box or flex box.

Comment: I changed block to flex and removed flex-direction, thank you for that tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the elements below the submenu to be pushed down, then you don't need position - `display: block;` is enough to show the submenu and push the other elements down.

**Working example**:

```js
$('.menu-arrow').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Marketplace</li>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Integrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Careers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Connect</a>
      <img class="menu-arrow mobile-arrow" src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <img class="menu-arrow desktop-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg" alt="arrow" />
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Newsletter</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bieberman, I was able to solve my issue! I have display flex and positioning all merged togther, with your solution and debugging i was able to figure it out!

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).